# Resistor failed open

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider

I am using this voltage divider circuit on a control board. Customer brought a board back stating the board wouldn't function after a few months in the field. After inspection, I found the 4.3kΩ resistor failed open. The resistor shows no signs of discoloration of any kind, but measures open. I've never seen a resistor just fail in this way. Has anyone else seen such a thing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that an SMD part or a through hole part?

Comment: And is 27v really 27v [max], or more like "may contain spikes up to 400v?"

Comment: Through hole part.

Comment: I am just monitoring a switch, 27V is the main power supply. I'm not driving a relay coil or motor or anything like that. Just a monitoring a mechanical N.O switch

Comment: Is it a particular brand, and composition? Thin film?

Comment: After trying to dig into this particular resistor to find the data sheet as requested above, I've found the resistor in question has been on our shelf since 2001. I guess it could be the shelf life?

Comment: I have 40 year old resistors I still use and equipment with 80 year old ones that still works fine given the correct 24month recalibration. It's not likely shelf life. Is the board used in a vibrating or very mechanical-shock rich environment? (Car / Truck / Other vehicle ) That would be a great avenue of research if so.

Comment: @Asmyldof They don't make 'em like they used to! ;)

Comment: @derstrom8 Okay, I also have all of that from about every decade to this exact day. There. Now I covered your loophole. And also the gap in your logic. :-P

Comment: Yeah, probably not shelf life...

Comment: @Asmyldof I was attempting to make a joke

Comment: Is that 27V internal to the box or does the wire run off somewhere, and if so, please describe it physically.

Comment: I added a diagram. The 27V is from an external power supply. The switch is monitoring an end of travel switch for a motor we're operating. Mechanical switch

Comment: If no mechanical or obvious faults are found with the resistor, I'd connect a storage oscilloscope up to the switched 27v wire, in a working unit, and monitor the voltage thoughout all possible uses of the device. Also consider the operating temperature and other conditions (humidity, chemicals, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your circuit is built with SMT resistors there is a good possibility that the failure could be due to a fracture of the resistor.

SMT fractures can be caused by:

1. Board flexing
2. Board vibration
3. Improper board handling
4. Stress in the component due to bad solder process
5. Being hit by a tool such as a screwdriver if the resistor is located close to a board mount hole or right next to a screw terminal block where input wires are connected.

If your board is built using THMT (through hole) type resistors then a fractured component could be caused by:

1. Board vibration
2. Improper board handling
3. Stress in the component due using too small of holes in board
4. Stress in component due to holes being too close together in board or bending the leads too close to the component body.
5. Being hit by a tool such as a screwdriver if the resistor is located close to a board mount hole or right next to a screw terminal block where input wires are connected.

Comment: It is a through hole part.

Comment: Several of the above issues could also apply to THMT type parts too.

Comment: Some of these causes may impact through-hole parts too, specifically (5) and to some extent, (1) and maybe (2).

Comment: Very well could be board handling as stated above. I'm going to look a little Closer at the resistor to look for fractures to help validate your suggestion.

Comment: Could try to very carefully desolder it, and/or snip it's leads and carefully remove it, then inspect under a microscope.

Answer (score 3):

Redo your calculations for worst case.

- Take resistor value at 90%.
- Unless your supply is very well regulated and stabilised assume it
  could easily be 141% of rated voltage under light load.
- Assume the ULN2804A input pin could get clampped to ground by internal
  latchups, substrate diodes, input bias current or part failure

  So you have 27x1.41/(4300x0.9)=9.83mA, 0.00983x27x1.41=374mW > 250mW

This will exceed the quater Watt rating on a hot day.

Induced voltage spikes may make the situation worse as you have motor and wire runs nearby but mostly we expect noise on wiring to be of low energy even if higher voltages so worse for semiconductor inputs than power dissipation limits on passive components.

I suggest you replace with a larger resistor value or wattage, apologise and offer a voluntary service recall to your customers, make them respect you instead of suspect you.

Comment: Good suggestion, advice taken.